# How to dynamically append particular div if selected option is changed?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm having a dropdown which has 3 options English Hindi Marathi. When the user selects the Hindi, the label containing the Hindi text should be shown and the other two should be hidden. The dropdown is as below:

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <select id="languageId">
        <option>English</option>
        <option>Hindi</option>
        <option>Marathi</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```
<label id="english">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</label>

<label id="hindi">लोगो संस्थान सिद्धांत उपयोगकर्ता लक्षण दौरान अतित प्रमान बातसमय वैश्विक विकसित प्रौध्योगिकी लेकिन उनका होसके करता मानसिक अनुवाद तकनिकल तकनिकल यायेका प्राथमिक सदस्य लोगो परिभाषित बीसबतेबोध बारे पहोच।</label>

<label id="marathi">यदि आप इस साइट का नियमित रूप से इस्तेमाल करते हैं और इस साइट को इंटरनेट पर बनाये रखना चाहते हैं,</label>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
$('#languageId').on('change', function(e) {
      if($(this).val() == 'Hindi') {
          var hindi = document.getElementById('hindi');
          hindi.style.removeProperty("display");
          $('#english').css('display','none');
          $('#marathi').css('display','none');
      }
      if($(this).val() == 'English') {
          var english = document.getElementById('english');
          english.style.removeProperty("display");
          $('#hindi').css('display','none');
          $('#marathi').css('display','none');
      }
      if($(this).val() == 'Marathi') {
          var marathi = document.getElementById('marathi');
          marathi.style.removeProperty("display");
          $('#hindi').css('display','none');
          $('#english').css('display','none');
      }
}
```

Can anyone please help me in displaying only the text in the selected language and other language text should be hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<option>` tags should have the `value` attribute. Like this

```
<option value="English">English</option>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vxs2u4m6/5/